Enclosure considerations for resin printer
I am doing research on buying my first 3D resin printer, and I really want to ensure I have a good enclosure to handle the venting of resin odor/off gassing. I am looking at buying a vented enclosure so that I can use a fan to extract the odor through a duct line. I have seen a couple ready made enclosures that do this, however they only fit the resin printer. Other people have suggested using a grow tent, modified for my purpose -- advantage being is that there is more room within the enclosure.
I would like to know if there are any odor/off gassing concerns once the model is removed from the printer? I am wondering if either the wash station or a curing station could also benefit from being in a vented enclosure?

The vast majority of resin printers on the market do not require an enclosure, and derive little to no benefit from having one, because the plastic cover provided with them fulfills this function.
The primary reason that you might want to use an enclosure would be if you are printing in a cold environment, such as an outbuilding or shed, or an unheated warehouse print farm. In this case the enclosure would be to keep the heat from a resin\VAT heater inside the printer's plastic cover.
I have one of those black insulated slip on covers, but it's to keep UV out as my printer is next to a window in full sunlight most of the day which can "over time" effect resin left in the vat. It just lets me go longer without cleaning it properly, it's unnecessary during printing. I take it off so that I can see if a print has failed.
When it comes to fumes, vented enclosures are largely unnecessary if you have a single printer, and it's not located somewhere like next to your bed (and it's not left running while you sleep).
In most use cases they're an unnecessary after market gadget that's designed to get people to spend more money on something that they don't really need.
The fumes from modern resins are only dangerous in unventilated spaces. The resins come with a material data sheet or safety data sheet (it may be called something different where you are, or if you aren't using a Resin sold in the US), this will tell you the dangers and tolerances.
The short answer is that if you plan to ventilate your printer and you have a window to put a vent pipe out of, it's just as effective to open the window and ventilate the entire room.
If you really do feel unsafe, the bigger printer brands such as Elegoo and Creality include pre cut mounts for ventilation hoses in their plastic covers. Buy a printer with a pre made outlet and attach a ventilation hose to it, rather than buying an after market enclosure. It will be cheaper and will take up less space on your desktop.
Once a model has been removed from the printer it will smell but it won't off gas enough to be dangerous, open a window.
The wash stations are a little different. IPA does give off fumes, you don't want to wash a print in your bedroom as it will smell. Opening a window will also be sufficient to keep you safe.
The main advice is quite simply to open a window. Washing your resin models in water after they've been washed in IPA and cursed also helps.
But unless you are running a print farm, or have your printer in a small room next to your bed, opening a Window all you need to do.
